# asp.net availability calendar showing full year

Tags: asp.net, calendar, controls

I am looking for a asp.net control that will display a full year in a grid format, with each month as a row and each day in the month as the columns. I have found the following classic ASP script which produces the correct format: http://www.livio.net/code/calendar_36/CalendarTestYearly36.asp?infomode=HELP (see Yearly Calendar)

Is anything like this available or is there a way to do this simply without a specific control? I am new to asp.net.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whipped up this, just for you:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Yearly Calendar</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table td { padding:0; margin:0; border:1px solid #dadada; }
        table th { width:25px; text-align:center; }
        table td { text-align:center; }
        table td span { color:#dadada; }
        table td a { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }
        table td a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
        table td a.hasEvents { color:#ff0000; }
        table td a.selected { color:#0000ff; font-weight:bold; }
        table td.month { background-color:#999999; }
        table td.weekend { background-color:#D0D0D0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litSelectedYear" runat="server" />
                    </th>
                    <% for (int iWeek = 1; iWeek <= 6; iWeek++) {
                        for (int iDay = 1; iDay <= 7; iDay++) { if (iWeek == 6 && iDay > 2) break; %>
                        <th>
                            <%= GetDayName(iDay) %>
                        </th>
                    <% } } %>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <asp:Repeater ID="repMonths" runat="server" OnInit="repMonths_OnInit" OnItemDataBound="repMonths_OnItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>                  
                    <tr>
                        <td class="month">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hylMonth" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="repDays" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repDays_OnItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <td id="tdDay" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="litDay" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private DateTime _dtMonth;
    private DateTime _selectedDate;
    private bool _specialDaySelected = true;
    private int _currentBindingMonth;

    protected void repMonths_OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CalDate"], out _selectedDate))
        {
            _specialDaySelected = false;
            int selectedMonth, selectedYear;
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CalYear"], out selectedYear);
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CalMonth"], out selectedMonth);

            if (selectedYear <= 0) selectedYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
            if (selectedMonth <= 1) selectedMonth = 1;
            else if (selectedMonth > 12) selectedMonth = 12;

            _selectedDate = new DateTime(selectedYear, selectedMonth, 1);
        }

        litSelectedYear.Text = _selectedDate.Year.ToString();

        repMonths.DataSource = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        repMonths.DataBind();
    }

    protected void repMonths_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater repDays = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repDays");
            HyperLink hylMonth = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hylMonth");
            _currentBindingMonth = (int)e.Item.DataItem;
            _dtMonth = new DateTime(_selectedDate.Year, _currentBindingMonth, 1);

            hylMonth.Text = _dtMonth.ToString("MMM");
            hylMonth.NavigateUrl = string.Format("{0}?CalMonth={1}&CalYear={2}", Request.Path, _currentBindingMonth, _selectedDate.Year);

            if (_currentBindingMonth == _selectedDate.Month) hylMonth.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");

            if (_dtMonth.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
                int daysToSubtract = -(int)_dtMonth.DayOfWeek;

                if (_dtMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) daysToSubtract = -7; // Special case. US weeks start with sunday, thus the enum DayOfWeek.Sunday = 0.

                _dtMonth = _dtMonth.AddDays(daysToSubtract + 1);
            }

            DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[37];
            for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++)
            {
                dates[i] = _dtMonth;
                _dtMonth = _dtMonth.AddDays(1);
            }

            repDays.DataSource = dates;
            repDays.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void repDays_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)e.Item.DataItem;
            Literal litDay = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litDay");
            HtmlTableCell tdDay = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdDay");

            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                tdDay.Attributes.Add("class", "weekend");

            if (_currentBindingMonth == date.Month)
                litDay.Text = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}?CalDate={3}-{2}-{1}\"{4}>{3}</a>", Request.Path, date.Year, date.Month, date.Day.ToString("D2"), (_specialDaySelected && date.Equals(_selectedDate)) ? " class=\"selected\"" : string.Empty);
            else
                litDay.Text = string.Format("<span>{0}</span>", date.Day.ToString("D2"));

            // Clear ID's
            tdDay.ID = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public static string GetDayName(int dayInWeek)
    {
        switch (dayInWeek)
        {
            case 1: return "mo";
            case 2: return "tu";
            case 3: return "we";
            case 4: return "th";
            case 5: return "fr";
            case 6: return "sa";
            case 7: return "su";
        }

        return "God only made seven days in a week.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm giving this a try... 
Is there a simple way to access individual cells in the grid, or would this need to happen OnItemDataBound? Once I have the grid of days I need to have different html for individual days based on a data feed of availabilty dates, such that some are clickable, some aren't, some display in different colors etc.

Comment: See the new changes. To target specific days, compare the dates on ItemDataBound.

Answer (score 0):

You could build that with a combination of ASP.NET controls, such as two repeaters, one to render the months and one to render the days.  It's possible to do it that way.  It may be more difficult to include the other days of the month and to include the day of the week as depicted there, but its definitely possible.

The inner repeater binds the days, and the outer repeater binds the months.

An alternative may be to dynamically create a DataTable class and put all the logic to display the months within the table.  Create as columns in the datatable the days, and create a new row for each month.  That would work out too.

HTH.