# ASP.NET availability calendar showing full year

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a asp.net control that will display a full year in a grid format, with each month as a row and each day in the month as the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I use **DayPilot** when it comes to Planning and Calendars

> http://www.daypilot.org/

They include the [Monthly View](http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Month/) as you request.

Comment: I need to see all 365 days at a fetch

Comment: using the **Schedule** you can easily show the entire year events -> http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Scheduler/Year.aspx I use this view to show all events with colors (full booked or not) for the entire year.

Comment: Here I got a code but some events are going wrong i am unable to understand that........ here is the link                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724350/asp-net-availability-calendar-showing-full-year?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: you should read the documents and follow up the demos on their own website, I know it took me a couple days to "hook up" with their flow, but after understanding, all makes sense.